# Multi-Booting from Mulit-Hard Drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, wine

Hello and thank you in advance for reading this message.

I was not able to find an answer in the forum and while I'm fairly certain that someone else has had to have experienced this problem in the past, since I can't find the resolution, I figured it best to post the question and see where it goes.

Okay, so, to the point...

I have 3 hard drives on my system. One has Windows 8.1 Pro, one has Windows 7 pro and the 3rd (now) has Ubuntu 14. I am new to Linux so I'm going to be learning this operating system as I go but before I get started, I want to try and make things a little more comfortable for me as I acclimate myself to the different technology.
Initially, I installed Ubuntu (4 days ago) and got a "grub recovery" problem that I didn't understand and could find a resolution for so I removed Ubuntu from the 3rd hard drive, repaired my windows' installations by performing a few bootrec procedures and am now back to my Windows Multiboot preferred state. I also disconnected (physically since doing it in the BIOS didn't work) my 2 windows hard drives and performed a clean install of Ubuntu on the 3rd hard drive...

I now have all 3 drives plugged in and my Dualboot for Windows is working fine, but I do not get the choice to boot to Linux, I only get the Window's options in the multiboot and I would like to know how (if I can) to set up the multi-boot so Linux becomes one of the options. If it is not possible, I can always turn off the other 2 drives in the BIOS and simply work it that way, but I would prefer not to...

Also, I would like to know if it is possible to make a few changes to Ubuntu so it has a more replicated feel of Windows (again, while I acclimate myself to the new system). Things like, creating a task bar with a 'start menu' kinda of thing so I can more easily navigate to my programs... ... the reason for this request is because I installed "PlayOnLinux" (a WINE based program) that is supposed to allow me to run a couple Windows games that I like to play but I can't figure out how to find it, open it or run it and I assume that's because I don't know how to use the Ubuntu system...

So - long story short (and yes, I do apologize for the lengthy message, but the thingy at the top says the more info the better... lol), anyway... What I'm trying to do is "add" Ubuntu to my Windows 8 multiboot options AND create a friendlier 'visual' concept to the actual platform...

Again, thank you for taking the time to read this message.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, set the Ubuntu Hard Drive as your first/primary drive. Then in terminal run

*sudo grub-update*

That should automatically recognize the other Windows partitions on the other drives and add them automatically.

You can also change the primary boot partition in: */etc/default/grub*